# How do I map a path alias when migrating?

Tags: 8, migrations, path-aliases

When migrating from Drupal 6 to 8 i can simply map path aliases with the mapping:

```
process:
  path: alias
```

I have the problem that the path alias is not set properly when pathauto is activated for a node-type. The alias always gets generated automatically instead of using the old alias. How can I override this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly disable pathauto in your migration:

```
process:
  path/alias: alias
  path/pathauto:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: false
```

Comment: This will need the `alias` in the migration source. I found some details here: https://www.calebthorne.com/blog/drupal/2016/07/16/drupal-8-migrate-pathauto

Answer (score 0):

For 8.5.6 Core is working fine.
Another way for pathauto is:

```
path/alias: path_alias
path/pathauto:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 0
```

Regards! :D